# Stripe::InvalidRequestError Must provide source or customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-connect

order controller page

```
begin
    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
    token = params[:stripeToken] 

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
        :currency => "usd", 
        :source => params[:stripeToken],
        :destination => @seller.recipient

      )
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
    end
```

order.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
      false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id))
      $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

---

I am not sure why the source => params[:stripeToken] is not passing thru when I check the log in my stripe account. Is the token null?

Comment: Show us the logs. I suspect `params[:stripeToken]` is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you receive this error is because the publishable key is not in your form so when you send the form to stripe it doesn´t recognize you and it doesn´t send you back the token.

The process of charging a client goes this way.

1.- In your site you tell the user to type his card information in a form (hosted locally or just created by stripe script).

2.- Once the user submit the form. The information is submitted to stripe server with your publishable key. You receive a response from the server with a token. This token is forwarded to the action in your controller and since is linked to your account you can create a customer, a charge or join the user to a plan. This is the 'params[:stripeToken]'. The card information never reaches your controller, you just receive this token.

You can do two things to charge your clients, the first is create the form your self and the second just delegate it to the stripe script.

The first one is more tricky since stripe updates their api from time to time. It requires some knowledge of js and their api. For example Stripe v3 is different from v2. Allows more rationalization but requires more knowledge of js. The information and examples of how to configure can be found in [stripe elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

The second one is pretty easy. I recommend it to not advanced users. You can implement it just following the instructions in this link [using checkout and rails](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails).

I usually use the second option since it just takes 5 minutes and you delegate the hard work to stripe.